# How to seek a frame in video using `imageio`?

Tags: python, opencv, video-processing, python-imageio

I have a video and I would like to extract only specific frames from the video.

Currently what I do is:

```
index = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8]
img_list = []
for i, frame in enumerate(iio.imiter("imageio:cockatoo.mp4")):
    if i in index:
        img_list.append(frame)

img_array = np.asarray(img_list)
```

Is there a way to 'seek' to only the frames I want like it is done in opencv as shown [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33523751/getting-specific-frames-from-videocapture-opencv-in-python)?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can get specific frames by using the `index` kwarg of `imread`:

```py
import imageio.v3 as iio
import numpy as np

index = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8]
img_list = []
for idx in index:
    img_list.append(iio.imread("imageio:cockatoo.mp4", index=idx))

img_array = np.stack(img_list)
```

If you want more performance, you could use `pyav` as backend instead of the default `imageio-ffmpeg`.

```py
import imageio.v3 as iio
import numpy as np

index = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8]
img_list = []
for idx in index:
    img_list.append(iio.imread("imageio:cockatoo.mp4", index=idx, plugin="pyav"))

img_array = np.stack(img_list)
```

Timings (for 10 repeats each):

```py
>>> timeit.timeit('[iio.imread("imageio:cockatoo.mp4", index=idx) for idx in index]', setup="from __main__ import index, iio", number=10) 
9.865169799999876
>>> timeit.timeit('[iio.imread("imageio:cockatoo.mp4", index=idx, plugin="pyav") for idx in index]', setup="from __main__ import index, iio", number=10) 
2.250104900000224
```

---

This, ofc, has the drawback of re-opening the file each time, which you can avoid using `imopen`:

```py
import imageio.v3 as iio
import numpy as np

index = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8]

with iio.imopen("imageio:cockatoo.mp4", "r") as img_file:
    img_list = [img_file.read(index=idx) for idx in index]

img_array = np.stack(img_list)
```

Unfortunately, the `imopen` route currently doesn't work for pyav, because of a bug that I missed while writing the plugin. However, since I am aware of it now, I should be able to write a fix in the coming days :)

Edit: The bug is now fixed. You can now use

```py
import imageio.v3 as iio
import numpy as np

index = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8]

with iio.imopen("imageio:cockatoo.mp4", "r", plugin="pyav") as img_file:
    img_list = [img_file.read(index=idx) for idx in index]

img_array = np.stack(img_list)
```

Comment: Is the fix included in pyav v10.0.0? I encounter an error when trying to `image_file.read()` when opened with the pyav plugin, using that version from pypi.

Comment: Apologies, I see the fix was in `imageio`, not `pyav`. I updated that and now it's working.