# OpenCV/Python: read specific frame using VideoCapture

Tags: python, python-2.7, opencv

Is there a way to get a specific frame using `VideoCapture()` method?

My current code is:

```
import numpy as np
import cv2

cap = cv2.VideoCapture('video.avi')
```

[This](http://opencv-python-tutroals.readthedocs.org/en/latest/py_tutorials/py_gui/py_video_display/py_video_display.html) is my reference tutorial.

Comment: Heads up before you scroll down - any solution involving CAP_PROP_POS_FRAMES is not going to work reliably due to a longstanding bug in OpenCV.  See this thread: https://github.com/opencv/opencv/issues/9053

Answer (score 57, accepted):

Thank you GPPK.

The video parameters should be given as integers. Each flag has its own value. See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11420748/setting-camera-parameters-in-opencv-python) for the code.

The correct solution is:

```
import numpy as np
import cv2

#Get video name from user
#Ginen video name must be in quotes, e.g. "pirkagia.avi" or "plaque.avi"
video_name = input("Please give the video name including its extension. E.g. \"pirkagia.avi\":\n")

#Open the video file
cap = cv2.VideoCapture(video_name)

#Set frame_no in range 0.0-1.0
#In this example we have a video of 30 seconds having 25 frames per seconds, thus we have 750 frames.
#The examined frame must get a value from 0 to 749.
#For more info about the video flags see here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11420748/setting-camera-parameters-in-opencv-python
#Here we select the last frame as frame sequence=749. In case you want to select other frame change value 749.
#BE CAREFUL! Each video has different time length and frame rate. 
#So make sure that you have the right parameters for the right video!
time_length = 30.0
fps=25
frame_seq = 749
frame_no = (frame_seq /(time_length*fps))

#The first argument of cap.set(), number 2 defines that parameter for setting the frame selection.
#Number 2 defines flag CV_CAP_PROP_POS_FRAMES which is a 0-based index of the frame to be decoded/captured next.
#The second argument defines the frame number in range 0.0-1.0
cap.set(2,frame_no);

#Read the next frame from the video. If you set frame 749 above then the code will return the last frame.
ret, frame = cap.read()

#Set grayscale colorspace for the frame. 
gray = cv2.cvtColor(frame, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)

#Cut the video extension to have the name of the video
my_video_name = video_name.split(".")[0]

#Display the resulting frame
cv2.imshow(my_video_name+' frame '+ str(frame_seq),gray)

#Set waitKey 
cv2.waitKey()

#Store this frame to an image
cv2.imwrite(my_video_name+'_frame_'+str(frame_seq)+'.jpg',gray)

# When everything done, release the capture
cap.release()
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

Comment: In `python 3.5` using `cap.set()`, the first argument defines the frame number in range 0.0-1.0. So it's `cap.set(1,frame_no)`.

Comment: In cap.set() the first argument should be 'cv2.cv.CV_CAP_PROP_POS_FRAMES' without any magic '1' or '2'. The second one is the frame number in range 0 - cv2.cv.CV_CAP_PROP_FRAME_COUNT - it's an integer number, not float 0.0 - 1.0!

Comment: @AlexeyAntonenko it's important to note that the conversion to an "index" does not always work perfectly. It doesn't necessarily give you exactly the "index" frame, I'm guessing the developers just wrapped the old [0-1] code and there are rounding errors. I've posted a question / bug report on the OpenCV page because the actual bug-report link on their home page is broken. http://answers.opencv.org/question/200232/why-does-videosetframe_posindex-index-not-align-with-frame-number/

Comment: Using opencv-python-4.1.1.26, the cv2.cv.CV_CAP_PROP_POS_FRAMES is not found. Maybe the enumerations are off, but I had to use vid.set(1, myEndFrame).

Comment: @AlexeyAntonenko The magic constant `2` is actually `cv2.CAP_PROP_POS_AVI_RATIO`, which *does* take a floating point parameter between 0.0 and 1.0.

Answer (score 63):

The following code can accomplish that:

```
import cv2
cap = cv2.VideoCapture(videopath)
cap.set(cv2.CAP_PROP_POS_FRAMES, frame_number-1)
res, frame = cap.read()
```

`frame_number` is an integer in the range 0 to the number of frames in the video. 
Notice: you should set `frame_number-1` to force reading frame `frame_number`. It's not documented well but that is how the VideoCapture module behaves.

One may obtain amount of frames by:

```
amount_of_frames = cap.get(cv2.CAP_PROP_FRAME_COUNT)
```

Comment: `cv2.cv.CV_CAP_PROP_FRAME_COUNT` was not available for me.  I did find `cv2.CAP_PROP_FRAME_COUNT`

Comment: I guess you are using cv 3.x. Opencv 3.x defines those constants within cv2 module and without CV_ prefix. Opencv 2.x defines them within cv2.cv module and with CV_ prefix.

Comment: for cap.set you need to use frame_number as index from [0;amount_of_frames-1]. Following you suggestions, for a first frame we should set 0-1=-1, right? It makes no sense, since cap.set returns 0 after that operation. However, on some mp4 videos I can set 0 frame and num_of_frames frame and successfully read them (hence, read n+1 frames in total), which is apparently some rounding error.

Comment: The property is now named `cv2.cv2.CAP_PROP_POS_FRAMES`

Comment: Or just `cv2.CAP_PROP_POS_FRAMES`

Comment: Warning - `CAP_PROP_POS_FRAMES` is not reliable - it will often cause a silent bug.  See thread: https://github.com/opencv/opencv/issues/9053

Answer (score 29):

If you want an exact frame, you could just set the VideoCapture session to that frame. It's much more intuitive to automatically call on that frame. The "correct" solution requires you to input known data: like fps, length, and whatnot. All you need to know with the code below is the frame you want to call.

```
import numpy as np
import cv2
cap = cv2.VideoCapture(video_name)  # video_name is the video being called
cap.set(1,frame_no)  # Where frame_no is the frame you want
ret, frame = cap.read()  # Read the frame
cv2.imshow('window_name', frame)  # show frame on window
```

If you want to hold the window, until you press exit:

```
while True:
    ch = 0xFF & cv2.waitKey(1) # Wait for a second
    if ch == 27:
        break
```

Comment: What is the 1 in  `cap.set(1,frame_no)`?

Comment: Have a look at my answer below.

Comment: The '1' is for the property identifier. Property number 1 is for CAP_PROP_POS_FRAMES : '0-based index of the frame to be decoded/captured next.' More about this [here](https://docs.opencv.org/3.4/d8/dfe/classcv_1_1VideoCapture.html#a8c6d8c2d37505b5ca61ffd4bb54e9a7c)

Answer (score 19):

### Set a specific frame

From the documentation of the VideoCaptureProperties ([docs](https://docs.opencv.org/3.4/d4/d15/group__videoio__flags__base.html#gaeb8dd9c89c10a5c63c139bf7c4f5704d)) is possible to see that the way to set the frame in the VideoCapture is:

```
frame = 30
cap.set(cv2.CAP_PROP_POS_FRAMES, frame)
```

Notice that you don't have to pass to the function `frame - 1` because, as the documentation says, the flag `CAP_PROP_POS_FRAMES` rapresent the *"0-based index of the frame to be decoded/captured next"*.

Concluding a full example where i want to read a frame at each second is:

```
import cv2

cap = cv2.VideoCapture('video.avi')

# Get the frames per second
fps = cap.get(cv2.CAP_PROP_FPS) 

# Get the total numer of frames in the video.
frame_count = cap.get(cv2.CAP_PROP_FRAME_COUNT)

frame_number = 0
cap.set(cv2.CAP_PROP_POS_FRAMES, frame_number) # optional
success, image = cap.read()

while success and frame_number <= frame_count:

    # do stuff

    frame_number += fps
    cap.set(cv2.CAP_PROP_POS_FRAMES, frame_number)
    success, image = cap.read()
```

### Set a specific time

In the documentation linked above is possible to see that the way to set a specific time in the VideoCapture is:

```
milliseconds = 1000
cap.set(cv2.CAP_PROP_POS_MSEC, milliseconds)
```

And like before a full example that read a frame each second che be achieved in this way:

```
import cv2

cap = cv2.VideoCapture('video.avi')

# Get the frames per second
fps = cap.get(cv2.CAP_PROP_FPS) 

# Get the total numer of frames in the video.
frame_count = cap.get(cv2.CAP_PROP_FRAME_COUNT)

# Calculate the duration of the video in seconds
duration = frame_count / fps

second = 0
cap.set(cv2.CAP_PROP_POS_MSEC, second * 1000) # optional
success, image = cap.read()

while success and second <= duration:

    # do stuff

    second += 1
    cap.set(cv2.CAP_PROP_POS_MSEC, second * 1000)
    success, image = cap.read()
```

Comment: This is the more up to date answer.

Comment: I am getting, A warning "Could not find ref with POC <number>". Any ideas why?

Answer (score 7):

For example, to start reading 15th frame of the video you can use:

```
frame = 15
cap.set(cv2.CAP_PROP_POS_FRAMES, frame-1)
```

Answer (score 1):

In addition, I want to say, that using of `CAP_PROP_POS_FRAMES` property does not always give you the correct result. Especially when you deal with compressed files like mp4 (H.264).

In my case when I call `cap.set(cv2.CAP_PROP_POS_FRAMES, frame_number)` for .mp4 file, it returns `False`, but when I call it for .avi file, it returns `True`.
Take into consideration when decide using this 'feature'.

[very-hit](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4928269/very-hit) recommends using `CV_CAP_PROP_POS_MSEC` property.

Read [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36402322/4439762) for additional info.