# How to load partially a video file with opencv videocapture?

Tags: opencv, image-processing, video-capture

I would like to know if there is a solution to use opencv function VideoCapture to load a video not a the same time, but a certain numbers of frame given a timer ( loading for example 10 frames per seconde) . For example I could to load only the 1/10 of a video file at the same time.
Excuse me for my bad english.

Thanks

Comment: what is chrono ? Can you try to rephrase the question.

Comment: I've just edited

Comment: You could use the following to skip forward 10 frames at a time, if that is what you mean... http://stackoverflow.com/a/21359927/2836621